# Custom alert dialog view does not show things set dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have made an alert dialog which shows a custom view,

Java Code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_me_alert, null);
CircleImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
Glide.with(view).load("https://example.com/example.jpg").into(imageView);
TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText("This is a title");
TextView note = view.findViewById(R.id.note);
note.setText("This is a note");
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss()).show();
```

XML Layout- about_me_alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?attr/cardbackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When alert is shown, it reserves space for the imageview, and two textviews but does not set text or image.

NOTE: This only happens when I make a production apk for release, not while I am testing on my phone.

Comment: I have updated question with alertdialog code please check

Comment: I have also added a note specific to the problem